# How can I tell if SP3 is installed for my SQL Server 2005 instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-pack

How can I tell if SP3 is installed for my SQL Server 2005 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a pretty comprehensive page on figuring out your version in a variety of ways.](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-sql-server-i-m-running.html)

Comment: the sql2005 link only goes up to sp1 beta

Comment: @qntmfred - the Microsoft KB page you reference above is also linked on the page... "See [KB #321185](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/321185) for official Microsoft techniques"

Comment: ah cool didn't see that since it was under the version 7.0 section

Comment: Fair enough, I probably would've stopped reading when I saw 7.0 too!

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

How to determine which version of SQL Server 2005 is running
To determine which version of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 is running, connect to SQL Server 2005 by using SQL Server Management Studio, and then run the following Transact-SQL statement.

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

The following results are returned:

- The product version (for example, 9.00.1399.06)
- The product level (for example, RTM)
- The edition (for example, Enterprise Edition)

For example, the results resemble the following.

9.00.1399.06    RTM Enterprise Edition

The following table lists the Sqlservr.exe version number.

Release                Sqlservr.exe
RTM                        2005.90.1399
SQL Server 2005  Service Pack 1    2005.90.2047
SQL Server 2005  Service Pack 2    2005.90.3042
SQL Server 2005  Service Pack 3    2005.90.4035

Comment: SQL Server 2005  Service Pack 3 2005.90.4053 will be for the recommended security patch for SP3.